# Adding giphy-js to vanilla JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, giphy

I want to use Giphy SDK to my vanilla JavaScript project. The repository is this one: https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-js/blob/master/packages/components/README.md

If I clone it and go to `/packages/components/` and do `yarn run dev` I can run the example locally, so fine.

But now I want to create a JS and CSS file to add to my HTML and do not know how to transcript it (`yarn build` creates other files).

Comment: You should look at the published packages, rather than the source code: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=giphy

Comment: Thanks for your answer and improved text @jonrsharpe! The thing is it is not explained how to buid the code anywhere because I guess is more general concept I'm missing here. In general I don't know the process of downloading an npm pkg, use in my project and produce a single JS and CSS file I can add to production HTML. Again, thanks for you time!